# What does it mean when we say "The universe is smooth and regular on a large scale"?

Tags: cosmology, symmetry, universe

I am currently reading "Brief history of time",I have encountered this statement while the book discusses chaotic boundary theory,
according to which the early universe would probably have been very chaotic and irregular.
The statement-
"It is difficult to see how such chaotic initial conditions could have given rise to a universe that is so smooth and regular on a large scale as ours is today'
What does it mean by "universe is smooth and regular" here? And why is it difficult to be explained by chaotic boundary theory?
Until now I had assumed that the universe is homogeneous and according to that wouldn't randomness be able to explain the homogeneity?

Answer (score 2):

In this context, "smooth" means the average density of luminous matter in the universe is the almost the same no matter which direction we look in. "Regular" means that the distribution of big and small lumps of luminous matter in any given subvolume of the universe is also almost the same no matter which volume you choose to look at.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can you please explain why the randomness or the smoothness can't be explained by chaotic boundary theory?

Comment: sorry, that part of your question I cannot help you with.